# Please give me a suitable Jekyll index.md?

Tags: jekyll

This is the source code of the index I am currently using, but it will display the date in the title bar. I don’t know how to modify it. It can only be displayed: title.html

```
    <ul class="posts">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
      <li>
  　　　　{% for post in site.posts %}

　　　　　　{{ post.date | date_to_string }} <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>

　　　　{% endfor %}

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is nothing for the `index.md` file, but for the layout.

The HTML-Title is defined by the `title`-tag inside the `head`

```
<head>
  <title>{{ site.title }} - {{ page.title }}</title>
</head>
```

So you have to look check the layout definition.